# Pre-defining tabular structures in MediaWiki

Tags: template, mediawiki

I have installed a fresh MediaWiki. I want to fill it with articles that will contain free text, and tabular information in the right hand column, like Wikipedia does:

[image]

I want to pre-define templates for this information, and I'm a little lost on how and where to get started. I know how to create templates, I'm just not sure where to build these kinds of tables and define parameters that then get filled in in the actual page. This must be some sort of Wikipedia standard as almost every one of their pages has something like this, but I'm stumped as to how to use it in my own Wiki.

The default formatting guides are of no help, of course; I think I need to delve into advanced templates, but fail to find the right resources to start with.

Could somebody provide me with a few pointers to start with? The correct term for this or a manual link would already be enough.

Answer (score 2):

These particular templates are called infoboxes and you can find information on how to install them at etcwiki.org's [How To Install Template Infobox in MediaWiki](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/How_to_install_template_infobox_in_mediawiki) article and how to create them at Wikipedia's [Template:Infobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aInfobox).